# How do I build a Play project with Hudson?

Tags: maven-2, hudson, maven, playframework

I have a project that's using the Play framework, and the corporate standard is that all projects should be built by Hudson. However, I cannot find out how to do this, as Hudson does not follow any Java standards, and requires the framework installed at the computer it runs on. I have tried to build the project with Maven (if I had managed this, adding it to Hudson should be quite simple), but I have failed to make it work. I tried the [Play Maven module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/maven), but Maven claims it does not find the external repo that is listed (http://nexus.infin-it.fr/content/groups/public). This might be because I am behind a firewall. I also tried the recipe listed [here](http://www.sammyrulez.com/post/233787084/playframework-recipe-automation-with-maven-and-hudson), but the local maven build fails because it is unable to find `org.playframework:play:1.1:jar`.

Has anyone done this and can provide a howto?

Comment: What is the problem with having the play-framework on the hudson server?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, but in practice it is because of endless paperwork and quarreling with the operations dept...

Answer (score 3):

It can be done without installing the Play framework on the Hudson server, but it is quite complicated:

1. Put the play libraries (play.jar and its dependencies) in a Maven repository
2. Create a pom.xml for your project, configured with:

   - theses libraries as dependencies
   - your project specific dependencies (project lib directory)
   - the java sources folder of your project (in the maven-compiler-plugin): "**app**"

If your project is simple (no module dependencies), this pom allows you to build the play project java sources using Maven.

---

If your project has module dependencies, you will have to add the dependencies jar in your pom dependencies.

To do that, you will have to create jar files from the modules if they don't have packaged jars (to get the "CRUD" class of the CRUD module for example).

Comment: What about running the web tests from Hudson? Can this also be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can find some help on this page I wrote :
http://blog.infin-it.fr/2010/12/15/play-framework-integration-continue-retour-dexperience/

Even if it's in French, I put my Ant stuff and the Play's pom I wrote.

At work we managed to integrate our Play applications with Bamboo.
It should not be difficult with my files.

Answer (score 1):

Just looked at the repository, that you linked (http://nexus.infin-it.fr/content/groups/public). And guess what, I found the play-1.1.jar. However, the artifact ID is: **org.play**:play:1.1:jar and not org.playframework

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you could put the full Play zip on your build or in in your repository, and then use Hudson to kick off an Ant script to download Play to the Hudson agent, unzip it, and then run commands on it.  It's a little clunky, but it should work.